# jOOQ: Mocking DAO objects

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

jOOQ 3.5.0

I'm currently trying to write unit tests for a resource that is using jOOQs generated DAO objects.

I've noticed one of the base classes (`DAOImpl`) in the DAO hierarchy has many `final` methods which makes it unfriendly to mock (I'm excluding byte code manipulators like Powermock as a solution). I'm currently using the `MockConnection` and `MockDataProvider` pattern to fill in my DAOs but it seems like this is a little low level for asserting DAO method calls.

As an example, my resource is calling `FooDao.createFoo(foo)` and my point of interception in the test is `MockDataProvider.execute(...)` which provides me with a context object with raw SQL and a binding object array of values.

In order for the test to assert that `create` has been called, I would need to evaluate the raw sql. Seems wasteful to be doing something like this when the DAO has nice, fluent methods that could be asserted on.

So my question is: is there a better way to unit test DAO usage? Seems like I need A LOT of boiler plate in order to test one simple contract....

```
FooDao fooDao = createMock(FooDao.class);
....
when(fooDao.fetchById(id)).thenReturn(foo);
```

is much more preferable to the [example in the docs](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/).

Comment: What keeps you from using Powermock?

Comment: Alternatively, can you use [`DAO`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.x/org/jooq/DAO.html) instead of `DAOImpl` and program to (i.e. mock) an interface?

Comment: @Xaerxess There is too much detail in between `FooDao` and `DAO`. This means A LOT of boiler plate for me for EVERY DAO just to be able to write a clean test.

Comment: @LukasEder PowerMock is the interim solution but I'd like to swap it out for something cleaner. Those kind of tools cause problems in build / test suites (with recycled JVMs etc). It's good design that the API is locked off through final methods, but a generated interface without those would go a long way to facilitate lightweight unit testing.

Comment: @markdsievers: This won't lead to an objective answer :) but "something cleaner" and "mocking" are two fundamentally opposite concepts. You will always run into Java-language or JVM limitations when you want to mock things, so you might as well resort to bytecode manipulation and instrumentation. The mere idea of mocking is fundamentally opposite to encapsulation and other core OO/Java design tools even if TDD-evangelists like to pretend that this is not the case (in the context of Java). For instance, much of jOOQ is intentionally package-private, or even static...

Comment: @LukasEder thanks for your time, Lukas. I'll eagerly await interfaces I can mock, in the mean time I'll use PowerMock. :)

Comment: @markdsievers: That's actually a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, it will be hard to mock jOOQ DAOs without using something like PowerMock that removes `final` from bytecode for you in order to override those methods.

In a future jOOQ version, we might implement interface code generation for DAOs, however. Those would be easier to mock.

See also:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3868